# Regex in Google Analytics Core Reporting API

Tags: regex, google-analytics

The API is here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters

I'm trying to match this:

`/mysite/some-other-stuff`

but NOT:

`/Mysite/some-other-stuff`

(note the capital M v. lower case...I want just the lower case.)

The API has a filter and I'm trying this:

`ga:pagePath=~(.*)(m)ysite(.*)`

This matches both the lower case and upper case versions. Any suggestions on what might work? I've tested this with a few online regex testers and it seems like it should work, so I'm thinking there's something specific about the syntax that Google Analytics wants.

Thanks!

Comment: It is written there: *Case sensitivity — Regular expression matching is case-insensitive.* You might try a thing like `(?-i:.*mysite.*)` (or even  `(?-i:mysite)`), but not sure it is supported by RE2.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much. Please submit as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is written in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters): *Case sensitivity — Regular expression matching is case-insensitive.*

You may use an inline modifier group `(?-i:...)` where you explicitly tell the regex engine to match in  a  case sensitive way:

```
(?-i:.*mysite.*)
```

or even

```
(?-i:mysite)
```

since GA regex does not require a full string match.